# Icefaces & JQuery

Tags: java, jquery, jsf, icefaces

I would like to decide on the UI technology to be used. I'm considering to use jQuery for sure as a javascript framework, but would like to know if ICEFACES would be the right choice to be used with jQuery. I would like to go with Visual Web Icefaces Framework (Netbeans IDE). Please share your ideas here!

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If jQuery compatibility is your primary concern, the RichFaces component library ships with jQuery and includes special support for it with a `<rich:jQuery>` tag. See the [RichFaces Developer Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/3.3.2.GA/en/devguide/html/) page for this tag: [6.14.9. < rich:jQuery > available since 3.0.0](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/3.3.2.GA/en/devguide/html/rich_jQuery.html)

While ICEfaces doesn't integrate natively with jQuery, you can at least make jQuery not clash with ICEfaces's own JavaScript framework, [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/). See http://www.icefaces.org/JForum/posts/list/8787.page

Regardless, it would be wise to thoroughly evaluate as many JSF component libraries as possible before doing any heavy development.

Some good, popular, and free/libre/open source JSF component libraries:

- RichFaces (from JBoss, now Red Hat)
- ICEfaces (from ICEsoft)
- Tomahawk, Trinidad, and/or Tobago (all from Apache)
- PrimeFaces (from Prime Technology)

A pretty thorough features matrix of a whole slew of JSF (and some non-Java/-JSF) component libraries that may be useful to you: [AJAX JSF Matrix](http://www.jsfmatrix.net/).

Answer (score 2):

The question is if it is a good idea to look at the problem from the client-side, which means jQuery. If you want to program JavaScript forget about JSF. If you choose ICEfaces you choose to skip writing JavaScript code. In ICEfaces this becomes transparent and you can concentrate on the business logic.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should ask yourself what yours goals for jQuery and IceFaces really are.

If your main goals are to have a working set of core components which out of the box use javascript & ajax without any javascript coding, then IceFaces is a good option.  A project I work on uses IceFaces for the majority of its UI work, and hand-picks specific jQuery widgets and components to place ontop.  This works quite well.

However, if you are looking for a framework to integrate seamlessly with jQuery and be mixing jQuery and IceFaces everywhere, it might not be the best setup for you.  For that matter I would thin long and hard about whether JSF is the right approach at all.

Typically I have found that if I wanted to build a javascript/jQuery custom code/component heavy project I am often times happier with a lighter-weight solution, something like SpringMVC with plain ol' jsp pages for example ends up having less complications with heavy javascript/jQuery work.